# Is it possible to group a DQL query by a portion of the primary key and return records with max() datetime record (earlier than a reference date)?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

In a doctrine query, how can I `group by` only some of the variables in a composite primary key? In the case below, `Category` and `Product` (but not `Iterator`)?

## Example

The below table, should keep a history of price changes over time (`Transactions`). I am trying to write a doctrine query to return the latest dated record (that precedes a reference date):

```
Category (PK) | Product (PK) | Iterator (PK) | CreateDT   | Amount
1               1              1               2016-01-01   100
1               1              2               2016-04-01   150
1               2              1               2016-09-01   50
2               1              1               2016-01-01   75
2               1              2               2016-01-31   80
2               1              3               2016-09-01   90
```

Using the above as reference, the result I am trying to get is one record per Category/Product as below:

a). Considering `Category=1` and comparing against a reference date `2016-02-01`:

```
Category (PK) | Product (PK) | Iterator (PK) | CreateDT   | Amount
1               1              1               2016-01-01   100
1               2              1               2016-09-01   50
```

b). Only comparing against a reference date `2016-02-01`:

```
Category (PK) | Product (PK) | Iterator (PK) | CreateDT   | Amount
1               1              1               2016-01-01   100
1               2              1               2016-09-01   50
2               1              2               2016-01-31   80
```

## Code

My attempt is with the below but it does not work (in an ideal world, I would like `$category to be optional):

```
public function findActiveIterationByDate($category, $refdate)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT b3 
             FROM AppBundle:Transaction t1
             INNER JOIN
             (SELECT t2 
              FROM AppBundle:Transaction t2, max(createDT) as createDT 
              WHERE t2.Category=$category, t2.createDT <= $refdate 
              GROUP BY t2.Category, t2.Product) as t3
             ON t1.Category=t3.Category AND t1.Product=t3.Product'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
```

## Error

However, attempting this gives me the below error - I'm not sure if the problem is my INNER JOIN or DQL is not able to group by a partial primary key?

> [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
>     [Semantical Error] line 0, col 102 near '(SELECT t2
>     ': Error: Class '(' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you can't use a subquery in `JOIN` statement. You can see it in [DQL syntax declartation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#from-join-and-index-by). More specifically `Join` and `JoinAssociationDeclaration` definitions.

I think you could move the `INNER JOIN` statement into a `SELECT` subquery and make the `WHERE` conditions more restrictive if possible even though this would probably decrease performance.

Maybe even better would be writing a [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and map the result to Doctrine entities which is relatively simple and well documented. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-resultsetmapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Martin - the only reason I was trying to use composite keys was to maximize performance. However, if it *could* decrease performance then it's not what I was looking for - I will take them out and replace them with arbitrary `id` primary keys...!

Comment: If performance is important then use Native SQL where you can do anything you want and just map the result to Doctrine entities.